# Como automatizo el nombre de archivo en archivo bat

Tags: cmd, script, batch, sqlite3

El siguiente código me abre un archivo db (lenguaje sqlite) y me exporta lo resultante de una query a un archivo en mi escritorio. Hasta acá todo bien. Lo que yo quiero es que el nombre del archivo sea diferente cada vez que se ejecute el batch.

```
sqlite3 -cmd ".headers on" -cmd ".separator '|'" -cmd ".once holaa.xlsx" -cmd "SELECT * FROM analysis;"  C:\ProgramData\PROISER\ISASPSUS\datastore\dsfile.db <nul
```

A demás me está sucediendo que ejecutarlo dándole doble click me funciona bien pero haciéndolo desde uan tarea programada no me crea el archivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad estás haciendo dos preguntas en una.

## 1. Cómo hacer que el nombre del archivo sea diferente, cada vez que se ejecuta.

No das mayores especificaciones, así que utilizaré la vieja técnica de hacer que el nombre del archivo contenga la fecha y hora, de esta manera, cada vez que lo ejecutas, tendrá un nombre diferente.

Para lograr esto, me valdré de una variable de entorno, a la que asigno el valor de la fecha y hora actual, y finalmente la utilizo como parámetro para crear el archivo:

```
set fch=%date:~11,4%%date:~8,2%%date:~5,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
sqlite3 -cmd ".headers on" -cmd ".separator '|'" -cmd ".once holaa%fch%.xlsx" -cmd "SELECT * FROM analysis;"  C:\ProgramData\PROISER\ISASPSUS\datastore\dsfile.db <nul
```

Las posiciones que utilizo para construir el valor de la variable `fch` dependen de la configuración regional, es probable que en tu equipo debas realizar algún ajuste para que funcione.

Para probar en tu equipo, puedes crear y ejecutar este bat:

```
@echo off
set fch=%date:~11,4%%date:~8,2%%date:~5,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
echo %fch%
```

En mi equipo, produce el siguiente resultado:

[image: resultado de ejecutar bat con set de variable de fecha y hora]

## 2. Desde una tarea programada no crea el archivo.

Acá pueden estar ocurriendo una o dos de los problemas que describo a continuación.

- La tarea programada se ejecuta bajo una cuenta de usuario, que puede ser la del sistema, la que tu indicas al momento de crear la tarea (usuario y contraseña) o la cuenta con la que se inició sesión en Windows. Esta cuenta de usuarios debe tener permisos de lectura y ejecución a la carpeta donde se encuentra el archivo .bat (y los programas que invoque) y permisos de escritura a la carpeta donde se deposita el archivo de salida. Si la cuenta no tiene los permisos suficientes, no encontrarás el resultado.

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Tu script incluye una ruta relativa para el archivo de salida. Es común creer que esta ruta siempre será la carpeta donde está el .bat, pero la ruta actual del proceso puede ser otra. Si no indicas la ruta actual al momento de crear la acción de la tarea programada, será la ruta por defecto del programador (que ahora no sabría decir cual es). Puedes resolver esto, o bien indicando una ruta absoluta para que el archivo se cree siempre en la misma carpeta, o bien fijándote de indicar la ruta actual del proceso al momento de crear la acción, según se muestra en la imagen (en Windows 10):

  [image: Diálogo de acción en el programador de tareas]

Comment: Excelente, ya me sirivió lo primero.Haciendo los pasos para el segundo, no me ejecuta nada.

Comment: ¿Cuáles de todos _los pasos_ para el segundo?

Comment: El de inciar en opcion, no me trajo resultados. El de interactive, no lo puedo poner en esa clase.

Comment: Santiago, estás seguro que el usuario con el que se ejecuta la tarea tiene permisos de lectura/escritura en la carpeta de destino?

Comment: Sería mi propia carpeta, no tendría por qué haber permisos denengados.

Comment: Es lo que trato de explicarte, Santiago, que la tarea desde el programador de tareas, no necesariamente se ejecuta bajo la cuenta de TU usuario, a menos que la configures de esa manera en el diálogo que muestra mi respuesta. Esta tarea podría estar ejecutándose sin los permisos que requiere poder generar el archivo. También considera colocar una ruta absoluta.

Comment: Ya lo pude resolver, me olvidé en informarte y actualizarte el caso. Saludos y gracias

Comment: Que bien, sería interesante saber si te ayudó algo de lo dicho acá, o era otra cosa.

Comment: La verdad es que me ayudó toda la segunda parte del punto 2. Menos la parte de cambiar el usuario a interactive. Me sucede igual que el código se ejecuta bien solo parte del día, ya que en al otra parte genera errores cómo que no crea el archivo o lo crea sin formato. Igual para mi suerte, creo que la parte del día que quiero que funcione, lo hace bien. Saludos y gracias